# How does refractive index of an ideal gas depend on temperature, pressure, and density?

Tags: refraction, ideal-gas

Is there a reasonably simple (pen and paper) yet good approximation for the refractive index of an ideal gas as a function of temperature, pressure, and density. How would one derive this?

Thanks for any help.